# Expression of character of coset representation

Tags: representation-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group with subgroup $H$. Consider the set of all cosets $G/H$ and a corresponding transversal $\{x_1,...,x_m\}$. We now have a representation $\rho$ of $G$ on $\mathbb{C}[G/H]$: $$\rho_g(x_iH)=(gx_i)H.$$

**Problem:** *Find the character $\chi_\rho(g)$ for $g\in G$ in terms of cardinality of certain cosets. Give the expression when $H\triangleleft  G$.*

I understand that the matrices $[\rho_g]$ will be permutation matrices with $1$ on diagonal entry $(k,k)$ iff $x_k^{-1}gx_k\in H.$ To find the character $\chi_\rho(g)$, I need the number of $x_k$'s that conjugate $g$ to an element of $H$. I am stuck here. Please help.

Comment: Have you written up what happens when the subgroup is normal? This case is somewhat easier to start with.

Comment: You can show $\chi_\rho(g) = |g^G \cap H| |C_G(g)| / |H|$ but that's not really "in terms of cardinality of certain cosets"

Comment: I got @mt_ 's answer. But can you give a hint as to how to use the fact that  $H$ is normal when we are given $H\triangleleft G$?

Comment: A hint in the normal case is to show that if $g \in H$ then $g$ fixes everything and otherwise it fixes nothing. Or you can use the formula I gave and prove that $g^G \cap H$ is either $g^G$ or $\emptyset$ according as $g \in $ or $\notin H$.